# How can I combine two HashMap objects containing the same types?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two `HashMap` objects defined like so:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I also have a third `HashMap` object:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map3;
```

How can I merge `map1` and `map2` together into `map3`?

Comment: After seeing all the responses, and reading https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-maps it seems like there is no clean way to do this with lambdas. Disappointing.

Answer (score 426):

```
map3 = new HashMap<>();

map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```

Comment: thank you, I am merging the Maps in a for loop which uses a method return a map and need to merge it to another map and apply the same method agian. For this, i get null pointer exception with putAll method. it does not help using try/catch block. what should i do?

I am apply if condition, that if size==o then don't apply putAll else apply it and so on....

Comment: If you get a NPE, then apparently you did not initialize one of your objects properly. Do you print the stacktrace in the catch block? So you know *where* the problem arises. But unless you post the full and exact code including the stack trace you will need to track that down on your own.

Comment: Note that, with this solution, if a key exists in both maps, the value in map2 will be preserved and the value in map1 lost.

Comment: @MichaelScheper: what else do you expect? Keys in a `Map` are by definition unique

Comment: I don't know what the OPer expects. Maybe he expects the map1 values to have precedence, or an exception to be thrown, or for some 'merging' operation to be performed on intersecting Integers. Or maybe, since this is a beginner's question, this is a case the OPer hadn't considered, in which case my comment would hopefully be helpful.

Comment: Why not just say `map1.putAll(map2)`? Would that merge `map1` and `map2`?

Comment: See Jeffrey Bosboom's answer, that addresses @MichaelScheper concern.

Comment: Since we know the size of `map1` and `map2`, is there there way to make sure the backing array for `map3` is large enough to hold all of the values from `map1` and `map2` so that we only have to size the array once instead of twice (potentially for each `putAll` call)?

Answer (score 129):

If you know you don't have duplicate keys, or you want values in `map2` to overwrite values from `map1` for duplicate keys, you can just write

```
map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
```

If you need more control over how values are combined, you can use [`Map.merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-), added in Java 8, which uses a user-provided `BiFunction` to merge values for duplicate keys.  `merge` operates on individual keys and values, so you'll need to use a loop or `Map.forEach`.  Here we concatenate strings for duplicate keys:

```
map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map2.entrySet())
    map3.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), String::concat);
//or instead of the above loop
map2.forEach((k, v) -> map3.merge(k, v, String::concat));
```

If you know you don't have duplicate keys and want to enforce it, you can use a merge function that throws an `AssertionError`:

```
map2.forEach((k, v) ->
    map3.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) ->
        {throw new AssertionError("duplicate values for key: "+k);}));
```

Taking a step back from this specific question, the Java 8 streams library provides `toMap` and `groupingBy` [Collectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).  If you're repeatedly merging maps in a loop, you may be able to restructure your computation to use streams, which can both clarify your code and enable easy parallelism using a parallel stream and concurrent collector.

Answer (score 79):

One-liner using Java 8 Stream API:

```
map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))
```

Among the benefits of this method is ability to pass a merge function, which will deal with values that have the same key, for example:

```
map3 = Stream.of(map1, map2).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, Math::max))
```

Comment: this will throw IllegalStateException for duplicate keys

Comment: @ArpitJ. that's the whole point of the second variation. Sometimes you want the exception, sometimes you don't.

Comment: I wonder why this answer is so less upvoted.

Comment: I would have missed this answer completely after being disillusioned by the other answers. I only used Cmd + F to reach this far after reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310807/714112

Answer (score 43):

Java 8 alternative one-liner for merging two maps:

```
defaultMap.forEach((k, v) -> destMap.putIfAbsent(k, v));
```

The same with method reference:

```
defaultMap.forEach(destMap::putIfAbsent);
```

Or idemponent for original maps solution with third map:

```
Map<String, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<String, Integer>(map2);
map1.forEach(map3::putIfAbsent);
```

And here is a way to merge two maps into fast immutable one with [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) that does least possible intermediate copy operations:

```
ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer> builder = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder();
builder.putAll(map1);
map2.forEach((k, v) -> {if (!map1.containsKey(k)) builder.put(k, v);});
ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map3 = builder.build();
```

See also [Merge two maps with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158605/merge-two-maps-with-java-8) for cases when values present in both maps need to be combined with mapping function.

Answer (score 36):

If you don't need mutability for your final map, there is [Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) with its [`Builder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html) and [`putAll` method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) which, in contrast to [Java's `Map` interface method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29), can be chained.

Example of use:

```
Map<String, Integer> mergeMyTwoMaps(Map<String, Integer> map1, Map<String, Integer> map2) {
  return ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder()
      .putAll(map1)
      .putAll(map2)
      .build();
}
```

Of course, this method can be more generic, use varargs and loop to `putAll` `Maps` from arguments etc. but I wanted to show a concept.

Also, `ImmutableMap` and its `Builder` have few limitations (or maybe features?):

- they are null hostile (throw `NullPointerException` - if any key or value in map is null)
- Builder don't accept duplicate keys (throws `IllegalArgumentException` if duplicate keys were added).

Answer (score 31):

HashMap has a `putAll` method.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: What is the runtime for this command? doc doesn't seem to specify. I would assume Theta(N)?

Answer (score 24):

You could use [Collection.addAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) for other types, e.g. `List`, `Set`, etc. For `Map`, you can use `putAll`.

Answer (score 13):

Generic solution for combining two maps which can possibly share common keys:

In-place:

```
public static <K, V> void mergeInPlace(Map<K, V> map1, Map<K, V> map2,
        BinaryOperator<V> combiner) {
    map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.merge(k, v, combiner::apply));
}
```

Returning a new map:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> merge(Map<K, V> map1, Map<K, V> map2,
        BinaryOperator<V> combiner) {
    Map<K, V> map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
    map2.forEach((k, v) -> map3.merge(k, v, combiner::apply));
    return map3;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Very late but let me share what I did when I had the same issue.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("India", Arrays.asList("Virat", "Mahi", "Rohit"));
map1.put("NZ", Arrays.asList("P1","P2","P3"));

Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("India", Arrays.asList("Virat", "Mahi", "Rohit"));
map2.put("NZ", Arrays.asList("P1","P2","P4"));

Map<String, List<String>> collect4 = Stream.of(map1, map2)
                .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                Map.Entry::getKey,
                                Map.Entry::getValue,
                                (strings, strings2) -> {
                                    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    newList.addAll(strings);
                                    newList.addAll(strings2);
                                    return newList;
                                }
                        )
                );
collect4.forEach((s, strings) -> System.out.println(s+"->"+strings));
```

It gives the following output

```
NZ->[P1, P2, P3, P1, P2, P4]
India->[Virat, Mahi, Rohit, Virat, Mahi, Rohit]
```

Answer (score 4):

A small snippet I use very often to create map from other maps:

```
static public <K, V> Map<K, V> merge(Map<K, V>... args) {
    final Map<K, V> buffer = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map m : args) {
        buffer.putAll(m);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>` to merge both hashmaps and avoid losing elements paired with the same key.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("key1", 1);
map1.put("key2", 2);
map1.put("key3", 3);
map2.put("key1", 4);
map2.put("key2", 5);
map2.put("key3", 6);
HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map1.forEach((str, num) -> map3.put(str, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(num))));
//checking for each key if its already in the map, and if so, you just add the integer to the list paired with this key
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
    Integer value = entry.getValue();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    if (map3.containsKey(key)) {
        map3.get(key).add(value);
    } else {
        map3.put(key, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(value)));
    }
}
map3.forEach((str, list) -> System.out.println("{" + str + ": " + list + "}"));
```

output:

```
{key1: [1, 4]}
{key2: [2, 5]}
{key3: [3, 6]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use putAll function for Map as explained in the code below

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map1.put("a", 1);
map1.put("b", 2);
map1.put("c", 3);
HashMap<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map1.put("aa", 11);
map1.put("bb", 12);
HashMap<String, Integer> map3 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map3.putAll(map1);
map3.putAll(map2);
map3.keySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
map3.values().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

Below snippet takes more than one map and combine them.

```
 private static <K, V> Map<K, V> combineMaps(Map<K, V>... maps) {
        if (maps == null || maps.length == 0) {
            return Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
        }

        Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
            result.putAll(map);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Demo example [link.](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2020/03/combine-hashmaps-with-same-type.html)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following input:

```java
    import java.util.stream.Stream;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.Map;
   
    ...

    var m1 = Map.of("k1", 1, "k2", 2);
    var m2 = Map.of("k3", 3, "k4", 4);
```

When you're sure not to have any key collisions between both input maps, a simple expression that avoids any mutations and yields an immutable result could be:

```java
    var merged = Stream.concat(
        m1.entrySet().stream(),
        m2.entrySet().stream()
    ).collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

In case key collisions are possible, we can provide a lambda to specify how to de-duplicate them. For example if we'd like to keep the largest value in case an entry is present in both input, we could:

```java
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        Math::max))  // any function  (Integer, Integer) -> Integer  is ok here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashMap<Integer,String> hs1 = new HashMap<>();
    hs1.put(1,"ram");
    hs1.put(2,"sita");
    hs1.put(3,"laxman");
    hs1.put(4,"hanuman");
    hs1.put(5,"geeta");

    HashMap<Integer,String> hs2 = new HashMap<>();
    hs2.put(5,"rat");
    hs2.put(6,"lion");
    hs2.put(7,"tiger");
    hs2.put(8,"fish");
    hs2.put(9,"hen");

    HashMap<Integer,String> hs3 = new HashMap<>();//Map is which we add

    hs3.putAll(hs1);
    hs3.putAll(hs2);

    System.out.println(" hs1 : " + hs1);
    System.out.println(" hs2 : " + hs2);
    System.out.println(" hs3 : " + hs3);
```

Duplicate items will not be added(that is duplicate keys) as when we will print hs3 we will get only one value for key 5 which will be last value added and it will be rat.
**[Set has a property of not allowing the duplicate key but values can be duplicate]

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Put maps in a List and then join

```
public class Test15 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("London", Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    map1.put("Wales", Arrays.asList("P1", "P2", "P3"));

    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("Calcutta", Arrays.asList("Protijayi", "Gina", "Gini"));
    map2.put("London", Arrays.asList( "P4", "P5", "P6"));
    map2.put("Wales", Arrays.asList( "P111", "P5555", "P677666"));
    
    System.out.println(map1);System.out.println(map2);
    
    
    
    // put the maps in an ArrayList
    
    List<Map<String, List<String>>> maplist = new ArrayList<Map<String,List<String>>>();
    maplist.add(map1);
    maplist.add(map2);
    /*
<T,K,U> Collector<T,?,Map<K,U>> toMap(

                                  Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,

                                  Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,

                                  BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
    */
    
 Map<String, List<String>> collect = maplist.stream()
    .flatMap(ch -> ch.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
            
            //keyMapper,
            
            Entry::getKey,
            
            //valueMapper
            Entry::getValue,
            
            // mergeFunction
     (list_a,list_b) -> Stream.concat(list_a.stream(), list_b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
            
            ));
    
    
    
    System.out.println("Final Result(Map after join) => " + collect);
    /*
    {Wales=[P1, P2, P3], London=[A, B, C]}
{Calcutta=[Protijayi, Gina, Gini], Wales=[P111, P5555, P677666], London=[P4, P5, P6]}
Final Result(Map after join) => {Calcutta=[Protijayi, Gina, Gini], Wales=[P1, P2, P3, P111, P5555, P677666], London=[A, B, C, P4, P5, P6]}
*/
    
}//main


}
```

Method 2 : Normal Map merge

```
public class Test15 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("London", Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    map1.put("Wales", Arrays.asList("P1", "P2", "P3"));

    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("Calcutta", Arrays.asList("Protijayi", "Gina", "Gini"));
    map2.put("London", Arrays.asList( "P4", "P5", "P6"));
    map2.put("Wales", Arrays.asList( "P111", "P5555", "P677666"));
    
    System.out.println(map1);System.out.println(map2);
    
    
    

    /*
<T,K,U> Collector<T,?,Map<K,U>> toMap(

                                  Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,

                                  Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,

                                  BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
    */
    
    
Map<String, List<String>> collect = Stream.of(map1,map2)
    .flatMap(ch -> ch.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
            
            //keyMapper,
            
            Entry::getKey,
            
            //valueMapper
            Entry::getValue,
            
            // mergeFunction
     (list_a,list_b) -> Stream.concat(list_a.stream(), list_b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
            
            ));
    
    
    
    System.out.println("Final Result(Map after join) => " + collect);
    /*
    {Wales=[P1, P2, P3], London=[A, B, C]}
{Calcutta=[Protijayi, Gina, Gini], Wales=[P111, P5555, P677666], London=[P4, P5, P6]}
Final Result(Map after join) => {Calcutta=[Protijayi, Gina, Gini], Wales=[P1, P2, P3, P111, P5555, P677666], London=[A, B, C, P4, P5, P6]}

*/
    
}//main


}
```

In Python, HashMap is called Dictionary and we can merge them very easily.

```
x = {'Roopa': 1, 'Tabu': 2}
y = {'Roopi': 3, 'Soudipta': 4}


z = {**x,**y}
print(z)
```

```
{'Roopa': 1, 'Tabu': 2, 'Roopi': 3, 'Soudipta': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new HashMap(Map.of("k1", 1) 
{{   putAll(Map.of("k2", 2)}}
```

```
//Options 2: if you don't wanna use an Anonymous inner class, you can:
Map m;
(m = new HashMap(Map.of("k1", 1)))
         .putAll(Map.of("k2", 2));
```

This is the shortest way to concat two Maps into a new Map, as far as I'm aware. For brevities sake, I use Map.of a lot for small Map sizes. Polymorphically, Map.of provides methods accepting between 0 & at most 10 key/value pairs, and when that's not enough, I usually write something like this to concat two Map.of Maps.

[Oracle docs for creating immutable Lists, Sets, and Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.html#GUID-23F23104-CCEF-43C2-92F8-663094050FA5)

Answer (score -1):

you can use  - addAll method

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

But there is always this issue that - if your two hash maps have any key same - then it will override the value of the key from first hash map with the value of the key from second hash map.

For being on safer side - change the key values - you can use prefix or suffix on the keys - ( different prefix/suffix for first hash map and different prefix/suffix for second hash map )