# Merging two Maps

Tags: java, dictionary, merge

I have two maps whose keys are `String`s and whose values are `Set<MyObject>`. Given two `Map`s, what is the easiest way to merge them such that if two keys are identical, the value is a union of the two sets.  You can assume values are never null and if it is useful, we can make these `Map`s `SortedMap`s.

Comment: If you have the possiblity to use Guavas [Multimap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap), you can simply avoid the problem, and merging is as simple as putAll(Multimap other).

Comment: similar, possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-containing-the-same-types

Comment: Should be easy to do with the [Map merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are we talking about `HashMap` instances. In that case lookup is O(1), so you can just take one map, iterate over the entries of that map, see whether the other map contains that key. If not, just add the set. If it contains the key, take the union of the two sets (by [adding all elements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) of one set to another)

To illustrate with some code, where I used a Set to have autocompletion in my IDE

```
Map<String, Set<Double>> firstMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Double>>(  );
Map<String, Set<Double>> secondMap = new HashMap<String, Set<Double>>(  );
Set<Map.Entry<String, Set<Double>>> entries = firstMap.entrySet();
for ( Map.Entry<String, Set<Double>> entry : entries ) {
  Set<Double> secondMapValue = secondMap.get( entry.getKey() );
  if ( secondMapValue == null ) {
    secondMap.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
  }
  else {
    secondMapValue.addAll( entry.getValue() );
  }
}
```

Comment: This will skip entries that exist in secondMap but not in firstMap

Comment: sam - he is editing the secondMap in place, so secondMap will be changed.

Comment: you can use - addAll method

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

But there is always this issue that - if your two hash maps have any key same - then it will override the value of the key from first hash map with the value of the key from second hash map.

For being on safer side - change the key values - you can use prefix or suffix on the keys - ( different prefix/suffix for first hash map and different prefix/suffix for second hash map )

Answer (score 31):

You can do this with a [stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) fairly easily:

```
Map<T, Set<U>> merged = Stream.of(first, second)
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> {
            HashSet<U> both = new HashSet<>(a);
            both.addAll(b);
            return both;
        }));
```

This splits the maps into their `Entry`s and then joins them with a [`Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) which [resolves duplicates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) by adding both values to a new `HashSet`.

This also works for any number of maps.

Some variations which produce the same result:

```
Stream.of(first, second).flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(...);
Stream.concat(first.entrySet().stream(), second.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(...); //from comment by Aleksandr Dubinsky
```

The third parameter for `Collectors.toMap` is not necessary if there are no duplicate keys.

There is another [`Collectors.toMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) with a fourth parameter that lets you decide the type of the `Map` collected into.

Comment: A bit more concise is to use `Stream.concat (first.entrySet().stream(), second.entrySet().stream())` and avoid `map` and `flatMap`.

Answer (score 6):

```
static void mergeSet(Map<String, Set<String>> map1, Map<String, Set<String>> map2) {
    map1.forEach((key1, value1) -> {
        map2.merge(key1, value1, (key2, value2) -> key2).addAll(value1);
    });
}
```

Comment: That is not totally right.. merge function signature is more like `merge(T key, V value, Bifunction<V value1, V value2, V result>` . so the right answer should be something like `map1.forEach((key1, value1) -> {
        map2.merge(key1, value1, (valu1, value2) -> doSomethingWithValues);
    });

Answer (score 4):

How about this (untested):

```
Map<String,Set<Whatever>> m1 = // input map
Map<String,Set<Whatever>> m2 =  // input map

Map<String,Set<Whatever>> ret =  // new empty map
ret.putAll(m1);

for(String key : m2.keySet()) {
    if(ret.containsKey(key)) {
        ret.get(key).addAll(m2.get(key));
    } else {
        ret.put(key,m2.get(key));
    }
}
```

This solution doesn't modify the input maps, and because it is short and relies on API methods only, I find it quite readable.

Note that [`putAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) and [`addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) are both optional methods in `Map` and `Set`. Consequently (and in order to get O(1) lookup), I'd recommend using [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Note that because neither `HashSet` or `HashMap` are synchronised you will need to look for some other solution if you want thread-safe code.

Answer (score 1):

The following should merge a `map1` into `map2` (untested):

```
for (Entry<String, Set<???>> entry : map1.entrySet( ))
{
    Set<???> otherSet = map2.get(entry.getKey( ));
    if (otherSet == null)
        map2.put(entry.getKey( ), entry.getValue ( ));
    else
        otherSet.addAll(entry.getValue( ));
}
```

I don't know what you've parameterized your `Set`s on, hence the `<???>`: replace as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested):

```java
// Assume all maps are of the same generic type.
public static Map<String, Set<MyObject>> mergeAll(Map m1, Map m2) {
  Map<String, Set<MyObject>> merged = new HashMap();
  // Merge commom entries into the new map.
  for (Map.Entry<String, Set<MyObject>> entry : m1.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Set<MyObject> s1 = new HashSet(entry.getValue());
    Set<MyObject> s2 = m2.get(key);
    if (s2 != null) s1.addAll(s2);
    merged.put(key, s1);
  }
  // Add entries unique to m2 to the new map.
  for (String key : m2.keys()) {
    if (!s1.containsKey(key)) merged.put(key, new HashSet(m2.get(key)));
  }
  return merged;
}
```

Note that this solution does not mutate either of its arguments.

Comment: What about keys that are in `m2` but not in `m1`?

Comment: You call `m2.getValue()`, but `m2` is a `Map` and thus has no `getValue()` method.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan: oh right, fixed that too (geez, see what happens when I try to code off the top of my head!)

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer,String> m1=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
Map<Integer,String> m2=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
m1.put(1,"one");
m1.put(2,"two");
m2.put(3,"three");
m2.put(2,"two");
Set<Integer> s=m2.keySet();
for(int i:s){
    if(m1.get(i)==null){
        m1.put(i,m2.get(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(m1);
```

Comment: This is simple program that explains how to merge two maps

Answer (score 0):

Note that all other answers will eventually augment the original sets which you might not want for all use cases, if you don't want that just use a third map as output and create a new set for each key

```
public static void merge2Maps(Map<String, Set<Double>> a, Map<String, Set<Double>> b, Map<String, Set<Double>> c){

    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<Double>> entry : a.entrySet()) {
        Set<Double> set = new HashSet<Double>();
        c.put(entry.getKey(), set);
        set.addAll(entry.getValue());
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<Double>> entry : b.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Set<Double> set = c.get(key);

        if (set == null) {
            set = new HashSet<Double>();
            c.put(entry.getKey(), set);
        }

        set.addAll(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to end up with immutable data structures to prevent manipulation of your merged map and map's Set instances then you can take this approach.  This solution uses Google's Guava library.

```
public <K,T> Map<K, Set<T>> mergeToImmutable (
    final Map<K, Set<T>> left,
    final Map<K, Set<T>> right)
{
    return Maps.toMap(
        Sets.union(
            checkNotNull(left).keySet(),
            checkNotNull(right).keySet()
        ),
        new Function<K, Set<T>> () {
            @Override
            public Set<T> apply (K input) {
                return ImmutableSet.<T>builder()
                    .addAll(MoreObjects.firstNonNull(left.get(input), Collections.<T>emptySet()))
                    .addAll(MoreObjects.firstNonNull(right.get(input), Collections.<T>emptySet()))
                    .build();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a method to unite non-null `Set`s as:

```
static <T> Set<T> union(Set<T>... sets) {
    return Stream.of(sets)
                 .filter(s -> s != null)
                 .flatMap(Set::stream)
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

then merging two maps `m1` and `m2` having `Set<V>` values can be performed as follows:

```
Map<String, V> merged
    = union(m1.keySet(), m2.keySet())
           .stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> union(m1.get(k), m2.get(k))));
```

Or even simpler:

```
Map<String, V> merged = new HashMap<>();
for (String k : union(m1.keySet(), m2.keySet())
     merged.put(k, union(m1.get(k), m2.get(k)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<K, V> Map<K, List<V>> mergeMapOfLists(Stream<Map<K, List<V>>> stream) {
    return stream
            .map(Map::entrySet) // convert each map to set of map's entries
            .flatMap(Collection::stream) // convert each map entry to stream and flat them to one stream
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (list1, list2) -> {
                        list1.addAll(list2);
                        return list1;
                    })); // convert stream to map; if key is duplicated execute merge fuction (append exisitng list with elements from new list)
}
```