# Merge two List value maps

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Anybody knows how to merge with Java 8 two maps of this type?

```
Map<String,  List<String>> map1--->["a",{1,2,3}]
Map<String,  List<String>> map2--->["a",{4,5,6}]
```

And obtain as result of the merge

```
Map<String,  List<String>> map3--->["a",{1,2,3,4,5,6}]
```

I´m looking for a non verbose way if exist. I know how to do it in the old fashion way.

Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795945/merging-two-maps/25152991#25152991

Comment: is a map of list, is not the same. I've seen those post before

Comment: in my case is even more complicated since the map is created inside an iterator, so I need to merge the last map created with the new one in every iteration. Thanks but still dont see how can works in my example. Maybe can you provide an example? I really dont seen it. Thanks!!!

Comment: If you're using Guava, and have `ListMultimap`s, then this is just `putAll`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general idea is the same as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23040630/1743880). You create a new map from the first map, iterate over the second map and merge each key with the first map thanks to [`merge(key, value, remappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-). In case of conflict, the remapping function is applied: in this case, it takes the two lists and merges them; if there is no conflict, the entry with the given key and value is put.

```
Map<String, List<String>> mx = new HashMap<>(map1);
map2.forEach((k, v) -> mx.merge(k, v, (l1, l2) -> {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(l1);
    l.addAll(l2);
    return l;
}));
```

Comment: Is the less verbose code that I found, so I´ll take it! ;) thank you!

Comment: An alternative merge function would be `(l1, l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(),l2.stream()).collect(toList())`. That’s the simplest Java has so far (without 3rd party libraries).

Comment: That´s reduce the verbose on the merge function, thanks!!

Comment: @paul It does reduce the verbosity but is a bit more complex (since it creates streams pipelines).

Comment: more than complexity it´s matter to me the speed. I guess is true that is less verbose but more expensive

Comment: If performance matters, the better merge function would be `(l1, l2) -> { List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(l1.size()+l2.size()); l.addAll(l1); l.addAll(l2); return l; }` to ensure proper initial capacity. But the question was about “non verbose way”…

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, which gradually flattens the structure until you have a stream of tuples of the maps keys versus the lists values:

```
Map<K,List<V>> result = Stream.of(map1,map2) // Stream<Map<K,List<V>>>
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) // Stream<Map.Entry<K,List<V>>>
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream() // Inner Stream<V>...
            .map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), v))) 
    // ...flatmapped into an outer Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>>>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Another option would avoid the internal streaming of the lists by using Collectors.reducing() as a second parameter of groupingBy, I guess. However, I would consider the accepted answer first

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **Set** instead of **List** and can do it like this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map1--->["a",{1,2,3}]
Map<String, Set<String>> map2--->["a",{4,5,6}]

map1.forEach((k, v) -> v.addAll(map2.get(k) == null : new HashSet<> ? map2.get(k)));
```

Comment: Besides assuming mutable collections and not handling potential absence of the key in the second map, I don’t see why this should require `Set`s. It would be exactly the same for `List`s.

Comment: because with lists, you will have duplicate values