# Stream reduction with wildcard types

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

I'm experimenting with [`Stream.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), and have run into a snag with the type system.  Here's a toy example:

```
public static Number reduceNum1(List<Number> nums) {
  return nums.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a);
}
```

This works for any `List<Number>`, but what if I want to be able to reduce a list that `? extends Number`?  This doesn't compile:

```
public static Number reduceNum2(List<? extends Number> nums) {
    return nums.stream().reduce((Number)0, (a, b) -> a);
}
```

With the error:

```
ReduceTest.java:72: error: no suitable method found for reduce(Number,(a,b)->a)
        return nums.stream().reduce((Number)0, (a, b) -> a);
                            ^
    method Stream.reduce(CAP#1,BinaryOperator<CAP#1>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Number cannot be converted to CAP#1)
    method Stream.<U>reduce(U,BiFunction<U,? super CAP#1,U>,BinaryOperator<U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where U,T are type-variables:
    U extends Object declared in method <U>reduce(U,BiFunction<U,? super T,U>,BinaryOperator<U>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
```

I get, conceptually, why this happens.  `Stream.reduce()` must return something of the same type as the source's elements, and `? extends Number` isn't the same as `Number`.  But I'm unsure how to handle this case.  How can I allow collections of a subclass (e.g. `List<Integer>`) to be reduced (or collected)?

---

If it helps, here's a more practical example that similarly fails to compile:

```
public static <E> Set<E> reduceSet1(List<? extends Set<E>> sets) {
  return sets.stream().reduce(ImmutableSet.<E>of(), (a, b) -> Sets.union(a, b));
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not directly, but great suggestion!  I'll post an answer with more.

Comment: What would `(Number)0` mean if your argument is a list of BigDecimals?

Comment: @assylias depending on the accumulator function that might cause a problem, but in this case it shouldn't - I want some sort of `Number`, not necessarily a `BigDecimal`.  The `Set` example may clarify when this might be useful.  I want to return some sort of `Set`, I don't care what implementation it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't actually with the `? extends`, but with the `identity` parameter to `reduce()`.  As Sotirios Delimanolis suggested, you can specify a bounded type `N extends Number`, but only if the identity value is `null`.

```
public static <N extends Number> N reduceNum3(List<N> nums) {
  return nums.stream().reduce(null, (a, b) -> a);
}
```

This is because both the wildcard and bounded methods cannot determine if the identity parameter will be the same type as the list's elements (unless it's `null`, which all types share).

The workaround is to use the three-argument [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method, which allows you to treat the result as a different type (even if it's not *really*).

Here's the `Number` example:

```
public static Number reduceNum4(List<? extends Number> nums) {
  return nums.stream().reduce((Number)0,
    (a, b) -> a,
    (a, b) -> a);
}
```

And here's the `Set` example:

```
public static <E> Set<E> reduceSet2(List<? extends Set<E>> sets) {
  return sets.stream().<Set<E>>reduce(
      ImmutableSet.<E>of(), Sets::union, Sets::union);
}
```

Somewhat annoyingly you have to duplicate the reduction function since the `accumulator` and the `combiner` are different types.  You presumably could define it once in a variable and pass it to both via an unsafe cast, but I'm not really certain that's an improvement. Using method references is probably the right way to go anyways.

Comment: You can simplify your "Sets solution" to avoid cast altogether and have shorter syntax due to method expression:

`sets.stream().<Set<E>> reduce(ImmutableSet.<E> of(), Sets::union, Sets::union);`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and managed to solve is as follows

```
public static Number reduceNum2(List<? extends Number> nums) {
    return nums.stream().map(num->(Number) num).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a);
}
```

Comment: That's true, you can just cast everything (you can also use [`Class.cast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) as a method reference, e.g. `.map(Number.class::cast)`). Using the three-argument `reduce()` overload feels more conceptually "correct", to me though - we're starting with a stream of `T` and reducing to a value `U`.

Comment: `(a, b) -> a` results in 0?