# Unable to understand this Java Stream+Generics example

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8, java-stream

Could someone help me to understand why this code behaves as described in the comments

```
// 1) compiles
List<Integer> l = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList<Integer>::addAll);

/*
 *  2) does not compile
 *  
 *  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 *      Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to <unknown>
 *      The type ArrayList does not define add(Object, Integer) that is applicable here
 *      The type ArrayList does not define addAll(Object, Object) that is applicable here
 */
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);

// 3) compiles
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);

/*
 *  4) does not compile
 *  
 *  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 *      Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to <unknown>
 *      The type ArrayList does not define add(Object, Integer) that is applicable here
 *      The type ArrayList<Integer> does not define addAll(Object, Object) that is applicable here
 */
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList<Integer>::addAll);
```

It has clearly something to do with the definition of a type in generic methods, it's an information that must be somehow provided... but why is it mandatory? Where and how, syntactically, should I have figured it out from the signature of methods `of()` and `collect()`?

```
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values) {...}

<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

Comment: No it has to do with the fact that you are not assigning the result. 2) compiles fine if you explicitely add `l = `.

Comment: What is the compiler error message you see?

Comment: I confess I tend to think of the Java 8 type inference as a black box: it's pretty smart, and can usually infer the right things, but when it doesn't work you just kick it^W^W add explicit types until it works.

Comment: I have removed a couple of examples, but @Tunaki, 2nd example does not compile in eclipse

Comment: In 1 and 3, there's a hint for the compiler that `Integer` should be used. In 2, there is not. The type of values in `of` is not good enough.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry for the edits, but why 4 is not accepted, for example... and furthermore, this will compile `Stream.of(1, 2, 3);` without any hints

Comment: #2 compiles (IntelliJ, Java compiler).  Which compiler were you using?

Comment: @Makoto I'm working in Eclipse

Comment: So are you using the Eclipse compiler then?

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794924/generic-type-inference-not-working-with-method-chaining) is related.

Comment: This compiles fine with `javac` 1.8.0_60, even 2)

Comment: I ran into a [similar problem with `Stream.reduce()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31041363/113632).

Comment: @dimo414 the more I keep trying, the bigger is the number of "inconsistency" I'm finding. E.g.: why the hell now this compiles `Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`? I'll probably just deal with it...

Comment: I'm using `javac 1.8.0_25`. For me, 1, 2 and 3 compile but 4 does not.

Comment: @Tunaki:  Java 1.8.0_66 doesn't compile #4.

Comment: in my opinion it is pointless to speculate why a construct is compiling and another not. The answer is probably in the Lambda specification, if anyone wants to read that kind of stuff.
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/lambda-0_9_3-fr-eval-spec/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this is not an answer which analyzes the Lambda spec on http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/lambda-0_9_3-fr-eval-spec/index.html, I nevertheless tried to find out on what it depends.

Copying two methods from the `Stream` class:

```
static class Stream2<T> {

    @SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs") // Creating a stream from an array is safe
    public static<T> Stream2<T> of(T... values) {
        return new Stream2<>();
    }

     public  <R> R collect(  Supplier<R> supplier,
             BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
             BiConsumer<R, R> combiner){return null;}

}
```

This compiles:

```
Stream2.of(1,2,3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll );
```

like OP's (2).

Now changing the `collect` method to by moving the first argument to the third place

```
     public  <R> R collect(BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
             BiConsumer<R, R> combiner,
             Supplier<R> supplier
     ){return null;}
```

This still works (5):

```
 Stream2.of(1,2,3).collect(ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll,ArrayList::new );
```

Also this works (6):

```
 Stream2.of(1,2,3).collect(ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll,ArrayList<Integer>::new );
```

These don't work (7,8):

```
 Stream2.of(1,2,3).collect(ArrayList<Integer>::add, ArrayList::addAll,ArrayList::new );
 Stream2.of(1,2,3).collect(ArrayList<Integer>::add, ArrayList<Integer>::addAll,ArrayList::new );
```

But this works again (9):

```
 Stream2.of(1,2,3).collect(ArrayList<Integer>::add, ArrayList<Integer>::addAll,ArrayList<Integer>::new );
```

So i guess when a supplier is annotated with the explicit type argument, it seems to work. When only the consumers are, it does not. But maybe someone else knows *why* this makes a difference.

EDIT: Trying to use a `TestList`, it gets even stranger:

```
public class StreamTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(TestList::new, TestList::add, TestList<Integer>::addAll);
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(TestList::new, TestList::add, TestList<Integer>::addAll2);
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(TestList::new, TestList::add, TestList<Integer>::addAll3);
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(TestList::new, TestList::add, TestList<Integer>::addAll4);
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(TestList::new, TestList::add, TestList<Integer>::addAll5);
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(TestList::new, TestList::add, TestList<Integer>::addAll6);

    }
}

class TestList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addAll2(TestList<? extends T> c) {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean addAll3(Collection<T> c) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addAll4(List<? extends T> c) {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean addAll5(AbstractList<? extends T> c) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean addAll6(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`addAll` does not work, but `addAll2`-`6` do work. Even `addAll6` works, which *has the same signature* as the original `addAll`.

Comment: Your effort deserves an upvote! I'll take a deeper look to your answer tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you struggle about compiler errors, you should include, which compiler you have used and its version number. And if you have used a compiler other than the standard `javac`, you should give `javac` a try and compiler the results.

When you write

```
List<Integer> l = Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
    .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList<Integer>::addAll);
```

the compiler will use the target type `List<Integer>` for inferring the type `R` (which matches exactly the target type here). Without a target type like in

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

the compiler will infer the type `R` from the supplier and infer `ArrayList<Object>` instead. Since an `ArrayList<Object>` is capable of holding `Integer` instances and provides the necessary `add` and `addAll` methods, this construct compiles without problems when using the standard `javac`. I tried `jdk1.8.0_05`, `jdk1.8.0_20`, `jdk1.8.0_40`, `jdk1.8.0_51`, `jdk1.8.0_60`, `jdk1.9.0b29`, and `jdk1.9.0b66` to be sure that there are no version specific bugs involved. I guess, you are using Eclipse, which is known for having problems with the Java 8 type inference.

Similarly, using

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

works but now your hint forces the inferred type for `R` to be `ArrayList<Integer>`. In contrast

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList<Integer>::addAll);
```

does not work as the compiler is inferring `ArrayList<Object>` for the return type of the supplier which is not compatible with the method `ArrayList<Integer>::addAll`. But the following would work:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList<Object>::addAll);
```

However, you don’t need any explicit type when using standard `javac`…

Comment: For case 4 it seem you suggest that the argument order matters for type inference, or maybe, following @user140547's answer, that `Supplier` would weight more in the balance than `BiConsumer`. Is it really the case?

Answer (score 1):

When confronted with this kind of situation, I feel the best way to understand the problem is with pure reasoning and logic. Type-inference is a beast that covers an [entire chapter of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html). Let's forget about ECJ and `javac` for the moment, think through the 4 examples and determine whether *a* given compiler could or should be able to compile it according to the JLS.

So let's consider the signature of `collect`:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

The questions with this signature is: what is `R` and how will a compiler be able to determine what `R` is?

We can argue that a compiler will be able to infer a type for `R` with what we're giving as parameter to `collect`. As an example, the first is a `Supplier<R>` so if, e. g.,  we are to give as parameter `() -> new StringBuilder()`, a compiler should be able to infer `R` as `StringBuilder`.

---

Let's consider the following case:

```
List<Integer> l = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

In this example, the 3 parameters of `collect` are 3 method-references and we're assigning the result to a `List<Integer>`. That's information a compiler could take: we are saying to it that the type used is `Integer`.

Okay, so should it compile? Let's consider the 3 arguments to `collect` separately:

- The first, in this case, is a `Supplier<ArrayList<Integer>>` and we are giving `ArrayList::new`. Can this method-reference refer to an existing method (constructor in this case)? Well yes, it can refer to the empty constructor of [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--) (as a lambda - `() -> new ArrayList<Integer>()`) because `ArrayList<Integer>` can be bound to `List<Integer>`. So far so good.
- The second is `BiConsumer<ArrayList<Integer>, ? super Integer>`. Note that `T = Integer` here because the Stream is composed of integer literals which are of type `int`. We're giving `ArrayList::add`, which can refer to [`add(e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) (as a lambda: `(list, element) -> list.add(element)`).
- The third is `BiConsumer<List<Integer>, List<Integer>>` and we're giving `ArrayList::addAll`. It can also refer to [`addAll(c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-): `addAll` takes as parameter a `Collection<? extends Integer>` and `List<Integer>` can be bound to this type.

So basically, with only reasoning, such an expression should compile.

Now, let's consider your 4 cases:

#### Case 1:

```
List<Integer> l = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList<Integer>::addAll);
```

We're assigning the result of the expression as a `List<Integer>` so we're telling a compiler: `R` is `List<Integer>` here. The difference with the case above is that we're giving the method reference `ArrayList<Integer>::addAll`. Let's take a closer look at this. This method-reference is trying to refer to a method name `addAll` which would take as parameter a `List<Integer>` (our `R`) and should be applied to a `ArrayList<Integer>` (the type we're explicitely using in the method-reference). Well this is exactly the same as what we concluded in the reasoning above; it should work: `R = List<Integer>` can be bound to `ArrayList<Integer>`.

#### Case 2

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

The difference with the case above is that we're not assigning the result of the expression. So a compiler is left to infer the type based on the supplier: `ArrayList::new`, so it should infer it as `ArrayList<Object>`.

- `ArrayList::add` can be bound to `BiConsumer<ArrayList<Object>, ? super Integer>` because the `add` method of a `ArrayList<Object>` can take an `Integer` as argument.
- `ArrayList::addAll` can be bound to `BiConsumer<ArrayList<Object>, ArrayList<Object>>`.

So a compiler should be able to compile that.

#### Case 3

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

The difference with case 2 is that we're explicitely telling the compiler that the supplier supplies `ArrayList<Integer>` instances, not just `ArrayList<Object>`. Does it change anything? It should not, the reasoning made in case 2 still holds here. So it should compile just as well.

#### Case 4

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList<Integer>::addAll);
```

The difference with case 2 is that this time, we're giving `ArrayList<Integer>::addAll`. Based from case 2, we know that a compiler inferred `R` to be `ArrayList<Object>` because of the supplier (that does not has a specific type). This should cause a problem here: `ArrayList<Integer>::addAll` tries to reference the method `addAll` on a `ArrayList<Integer>` but we saw that, for a compiler, `this` was inferred as `ArrayList<Object>` and an `ArrayList<Object>` is **not** an `ArrayList<Integer>`. So this should not compile.

What could we do to make it compile?

- Change the supplier to have a specific `Integer` type.
- Remove the explicit `<Integer>` from the method-reference.
- Write the method reference as `ArrayList::<Integer> addAll` instead.

### Conclusion

I tested the examples with Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 and `javac` 1.8.0_60. The result is that `javac`, behaves exactly as with our reasoning concluded: only case 4 is not compiled.

Bottom line, Eclipse has a small bug.

Comment: “_determine whether a given compiler could or should be able to compile it_” – I think you should not have this kind of reasoning without referring to the JLS for each specific case. _Human computation_ of the type inference does not imply that the same would be inferred according to the JLS. The JLS could have its corner cases that a compiler should reject, even if simple _human inference_ would allow them. All compilers should infer the same types.

Comment: @DidierL What I mean is that understanding what is going on should not focused on "is it a bug of javac" but "let's try to reason this through with what the JLS says and see what we come up". I say that precisely because all compilers _should_ infer the same types but it is not the case in practice, so we need to think that way, i.e. abstract ourselves of a specific compiler.

Comment: Indeed but you don't make any reference to what the JLS has to say for each specific case. I find your answer good for human comprehension but I'm not convinced that this reasoning respects the JLS.

Comment: @DidierL I agree; the thing is that since type-inference is a whole chapter, you just can't make a quote of a couples of sentences that explain everything. If it were the case, there would be no trouble understanding type-inference to begin with. But just so I can improve the answer, which part do you think would need a reference to a specific part of the JLS?

Comment: I think maybe the most important is why the compiler should infer `R` (only) from the `Supplier`. I am afraid however that most of such questions require a quite deep understanding of the JLS.

Comment: @DidierL It's not that `R` is inferred only from the Supplier. In case 4, it's that what's inferred from the Supplier and the BiConsumer is not compatible (more precisely, no compatible types can be inferred from the both of them): from the Supplier, the compiler infers `ArrayList<Object>` and from the BiConsumer, we are giving `ArrayList<Integer>`, and those two are not compatible.

Comment: I'd say that from the `Supplier` it should infer `* super ArrayList<*>`. Why does it narrow it down to `ArrayList<Object>` before confronting it with the `BiConsumer`?

Comment: @DidierL: maybe it is a nevertheless bug? see my updated answer's `TestList`

Comment: Starting with 4.6M1 ecj agrees with javac in accepting (1)-(3) and rejecting (4).