# How merge multiple maps and aggregate values results using Java preferred Java8

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java-8

Let's say i have multiple N maps with-> key:string val:Object

I want to merge all of them into one big map , and sum their object filed values:

for instance:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by vitaly on 21/07/2016.
 */
public class Merge {

    static Map<String, Container> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    static Map<String, Container> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    static Map<String, Container> map3 = new HashMap<>();


    public void initMaps() {
        map1.put("aaa", new Container(1, "title_aaa"));
        map1.put("bbb", new Container(4, "title_bbb"));

        map2.put("ccc", new Container(7, "title_ccc"));
        map2.put("aaa", new Container(10, "title_aaa"));

        map3.put("aaa", new Container(13, "title_aaa"));
        map3.put("bbb", new Container(16, "title_bbb"));
        ...
        mapN.put(...
    }

    class Container {
        public Container(int val1, String title) {
            this.val1 = val1;
            this.title = title;

        }

        int val1;
        String title;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Merge.mergeMaps(map1, map2, map3);
    }

    public static Map<String, Container> mergeMaps(Map... maps) {
        /**
         * HOW create one merged map that sums the values
         */
// The result should be: 
        //map(aaa, {24,title_aaa )   //1+10+13
        //map(bbb, {20,title_ccc )   //4+16
        //map(ccc, {7,title_ccc )   //7
        return map;
    }
}
```

Prefer Java 8 but it doesn't matter :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will [`putAll`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299742/4009370) work?

Comment: don't think it will sum the values of the "Container" class

Comment: What's your question? You don't seem to have a `mergeMaps` method. Are you asking for a solution to do all of what you are trying to accomplish, because then it doesn't seem like you've done enough on your own

Comment: I've updated the title , I'm trying to make sum of the values after merging maps. The putAll method updated only the last value

Answer (score 2):

Stream over the different maps, flatmap them into one. Then use `Collectors#groupingBy` to sort them via their different values (aaa, bbb, etc.).
Then stream over the result of this again to create new `Container` objects with the summed values.

Finally, use `Collectors.toMap` to create the map you need.

If you have any question, don't hesitate.

```
public static Map<String, Container> mergeMaps(Map<String, Container>... maps) {
    Map<String, Container> map = 
    Arrays.stream(maps)
          .flatMap(x -> x.values().stream())
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v.getTitle().substring(6)))
          .entrySet().stream()
          .map(e -> new Merge().new Container(e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(x -> x.getVal()).sum(), e.getValue().get(0).getTitle()))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> ((Container) e).getTitle().substring(6), e -> e));

    return map;
}
```

And here is the output

```
{aaa=24 : title_aaa, ccc=7 : title_ccc, bbb=20 : title_bbb}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Map.merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
private Map<String,Container> mergeContainers(Map<String,Container> a, Map<String,Container> b) {
  Map<String,Container> result = new HashMap<String,Container>(a);

  for (Entry<String,Container> entry : b.entrySet()) {
    result.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (aContainer,bContainer) -> MERGE_BOTH_CONTAINERS_HERE); 
  } 
  return result;
}

private Map<String,Container> mergeContainers(Iterable<Map<String,Container>> maps) {
  return mergeContainers(maps, new HashMap<String,Container>());
}

private Map<String,Container> mergeContainers(Iterable<Map<String,Container>> maps, Map<String,Container> merged) {
  return maps.hasNext() 
         ? mergeContainers(maps, mergeContainers(merged, maps.next()))
         : merged;
  }
}
```

Now in your code you can merge your maps with:

```
mergeContainers(Arrays.asList(map1, map2, map3));
```

Comment: If I need to use N maps ...need to call N times "merge" function ? ...Must be more generic way..