# How can I merge and convert two different kind of Maps in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am facing this issue...

I have this

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Both are going to be needed to convert into a json (to later send a request).

The issue is that I cannot send all as String since the app return a **bad request** status

So, I need fistly to merge this Two maps to convert them as JSON.

OR

I dont know if is possible to convert them separatly into **JSON** format and then add them?

Any ideas?

Im using jackson to convert to json.

Thanks

Comment: What is stopping you from merging the two maps and then converting the merged map to json? 
Ways to merge two maps is already shared here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954862/865033

Comment: thanks @VenkatMadhav but that wont work since I need to send integer as integers in the json, is not the same send {"id" : "10"} than {"id" : 10}

Comment: Well, you can merge the two maps into a 3rd `Map<String, Object>` and then let the ObjectMapper take care of serializing the primitive types.

Comment: I did that actually @VenkatMadhav please check my response

Comment: shouldn't this line "Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();" throw a compilation error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a relative easy solution, hope could help someone else.

I merged the maps and then converted them.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<String, Object> mergedRequestParam = new HashMap<>();
mergedRequestParam.putAll(map1);
mergedRequestParam.putAll(map2);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
String mapToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mergedRequestParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 this is one way

Depends on which list you want to be the result:

```
map2.forEach( (key, value) -> { map1.put(key, value.toString()); });
```

will result `map1` to contain also `map2` values converted to `String`

OR

```
map1.forEach( (key, value) -> { map2.put(key, new Integer(value)); });
```

will result `map2` to contain also `map1` values converted to `Integer`

And if you want the values to be unchanged:

```
Map<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map1.forEach( (key, value) -> { map3.put(key, value)); });
map2.forEach( (key, value) -> { map3.put(key, value)); });
```

The last one might be easier with simply `putAll()`.

**BUT**: if you want to make some checks like key collision or other checks/value manipulation these `Stream` solutions provide easy & clean way to do it, like:

```
    map1.forEach( (key, value) -> { if(checkKey(key)) map3.put(key, value); });
```