# How to use one to many Mapping in java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In `map` function of `Stream` we can convert one object to another, so we can covert one `Stream` that contains 3 elements of type A to another `Stream` of 3 elements of type B.

How do I convert 3 elements of type `A` `Stream` to 6 or more elements of type `B` `Stream` depending on condition?

In term of code.

We can do

```
Stream<B> converted = original.map( a -> new B(a) );
```

But how can we do like following ?

```
Steam<B> converted = original.map( a -> { 
    if(a.split()){
        return [ new B(a), new B(a) ];
    }else return new B(a);
});
```

I was not able to find and understand how to do that. Thank ahead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use `flatMap` in order to map each element of the original `Stream` to a `Stream` of elements of some type.

```
Steam<B> converted = original.flatMap( a -> { 
    if(a.split()){
        return Stream.of(new B(a), new B(a));
    } else {
        return Stream.of(new B(a));
    }
});
```

or

```
Steam<B> converted = original.flatMap(a -> a.split() ? 
                                      Stream.of(new B(a), new B(a)) : 
                                      Stream.of(new B(a)));
```

Comment: I would personally consider having `split` return a `Stream<B>` rather than a boolean, then you can just  do `original.flatMap(A::split)`.