# Map.merge .. non-static method cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code:

```
    public List<String> myMethod(){
    ..
    ...... 
    Map<String, Module> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Module> m2= new HashMap<>();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Module>> entries = m2.entrySet();
    for( Map.Entry<String, Module>  e : entries){
        m1.merge(e.getKey(),e.getValue(),String::concat);
        }
    .....
   }
```

I get error line here **String::concat** with the message *non-static method cannot be referenced from static context*

any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: The third argument to `merge` must make a `Module` out of 2 `Module`s.  `String::concat` doesn't do that.

Comment: it would be a lot easier if you would tell us, how exactly you want to merge them

Comment: Im not sure but what about this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-containing-the-same-types#answer-41980046?

Comment: it seems to me that you **may** want a `Map<String, String>` as a result based on the two existing maps. in which case you could go with `Stream.concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getStrProp(), String::concat));` or `Stream.concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(e -> e.getValue().getStrProp(), joining())));` otherwise the answer below should suffice. ultimately, you could update your post to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map::merge` takes a `BiFunction` as its last argument to merge the values where there is a key collision.

You'll need to find a way to merge two given `Module's` not `String`.

in other words, it's:

```
 m1.merge(e.getKey(),e.getValue(),(Module l, Module r) -> ...);
```

---

On another note, you can simplify your code to:

```
m2.forEach((k, v) -> m1.merge(k, v, (Module l, Module r) -> ...));
```

Comment: ... and `toMap` with merge function is other way. `m2.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(e->e.getKey(),e->e.getValue(),(Module l, Module r) -> ...))`

Comment: @HadiJ I think you meant `Stream.concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream())
               .collect(toMap(...))` if so then yes we could do that but that constructs a new map every time instead of modifying the existing one like `merge` does.

Answer (score 1):

Your map value is of type Module. String::concat returns a String, your third argument needs to return you a "merged" Module instead of String::concat.

Comment: @Eugene Do I need to delete mine then?